# IIS 10 on Windows Server 2016 not running my ASP.NET MVC website

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-10

I just bought a new Cloud based Virtual machine with Windows server 2016 installed. I also make sure IIS 10 has .NET Framework 4.6 and ASP.NET 4.6 installed.

[image]

My ASP.NET MVC application targets .NET 4.5 and is successfully published to the 'Default Web Site' on this server using Web deploy. (You can see all the asp.net mvc published files here)

[image]

'Default Web Site' uses 'DefaultAppPool' which has a v4.0 .NET CLR Version.

But when I open the web page in my browser, I received a '403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.' error. I did my research, to me it looks like the IIS never tried to open it as a ASP.NET MVC application. It simply tries to find a physical file with the same name as 'controller/Action'.html and of course it couldn't find it. Solutions I have tried with:

1. There's another post mentioning the 'UrlRoutingModule-4.0' in IIS Modules configuration. In my case, the routing module is not there for some reason. I added it, but nothing changes. Furthermore, every time I republish the website from VS, the module disappears after the deployment succeeds.
2. I also tried adding `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>`
      to my webconfig file, no luck either.
3. Run aspnet_regiis -ir on the server. It says the command can't be run on this operating system but still run it anyway. However, the problem is still there.

Comment: @mjwills I added a 'Hello world' html file to the root folder and name it 'bob.html'. Turns out the server wont even show that file to me..

Comment: @mjwills ok, now it shows bob.html… I restarted the website and it works. But still cant get MVC to work..

Comment: Check whether you talk of (a) the proper folder and (b) proper permissions to the folder. If any of hose are not proper, IIS can not see the file. Do not bother with asp.net until a html file works.

Comment: @TomTom single html file works, it successfully showed the content in bob.html.

Comment: Ok, then THIS part works. Now make a minimal asp.net app. SLowly build up.

Comment: @TomTom It doesnt work. I tried with several ASP.NET MVC applications. None works

Comment: What does the event log say?

Comment: @TomTom where should I find the log files?

Comment: I do not say log files. I said event log. Windows event log.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I finally got it work!!!

The solution is go to control panel and then click 'Turn windows feature on and off', then go to 'Server Roles' -> 'Web Server (IIS)' -> 'Web Server' -> 'Application Development', here you need to make sure both '.NET Extensability 4.6' and 'ASP.NET 4.6' are installed.

Apparently when IIS 10 is installed, these will not be installed by default. Thanks guys for all the help.

Comment: thanks man, i was struggling for 2 days on this, finally yours is the solution that worked for me.

Comment: In my case versions 4.7 were needed. Windows 10 Pro