# C# MVC Api Deployment Issue on IIS 10

Tags: c#, api, iis, model-view-controller, deployment

I did create a web API using Visual Studio 2017 and .Net Framework V 4.6, it's working fine when I run it from IDE and POSTMAN, but when I deploy it on IIS 10, it's not working. please see image attached.

**1. Working on IDE and Postman:**
[Working on IDE and Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzKcz.png)

**2.Not working when hosted on IIS 10 and browsing in browser:**
[Not working when hosted on IIS 10 and browsing in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjIv3.png)

**3.Not working when hosted on IIS and using POSTMAN:**
[Not working when hosted on IIS and using POSTMAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niGuU.png)

**4. API Project structure**
[API Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtcTI.png)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Your code is working, the issue you have is the deployment of your application to IIS. Here is one link [IIS 10 on Windows Server 2016 not running my ASP.NET MVC website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53042531/iis-10-on-windows-server-2016-not-running-my-asp-net-mvc-website) that might help you. If not, ask Google!

Comment: As far as I know, 404 means the page not found. I suggest you could re-check your domain binding to make sure you have bind the right IP address for your IIS web api application. Besides, I suggest you could try to use IP address instead of domain address to access  the web api.