# IIS 10 on Windows Server 2019 not running my ASP.NET MVC website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-10

I am able to run the ASP.NET MVC application from Visual Studio 2022 (on .NET 4.7.2) on my machine. I created a publish to the local directory and copied the publish into the client machine which is a server running Win 2019 Std.

I have enabled the .NET Extensibility 4.7, ASP.NET 4.7 for my IIS 10 on the Win 2019 Std server. I have also provided full access to `IUSR` and `IIS_IUSRS` to the publish folder on the server. Disabled the default web site on IIS.

I have searched and followed the instructions provided in [IIS 10 on Win 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53042531/iis-10-on-windows-server-2016-not-running-my-asp-net-mvc-website). I have also added entry into the hosts file.

However, when I try to browse the application in says 404 error.

Please help me with this problem.

Comment: Can you verify which .NET Framework version is on that machine? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed#detect-net-framework-45-and-later-versions You need to install .NET Framework 4.7.2 if this machine only has 4.7 or 4.7.1.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, please post more details information about 404 error, what have you tried?

Comment: I have verified for framework, it is  running 4.7.2

Comment: I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies to every one for asking this question. This was a problem I faced when installing my application client machine.

It turns out that the client IT did not configure the relevant IP Adress / URI on their internal routers. They found this now and informed.

The applciation is now showing hte login page as it is should.